# How to use WordPress HTTP API to download file from remote location

Tags: http-api, wp-filesystem

So this PHP code works for me:

```
    $ch = curl_init( TCS_CPDF_REMOTE_ZIP );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    $data = curl_exec( $ch );
    curl_close( $ch );
    file_put_contents( TCS_CPDF_LOCAL_ZIP, $data );
```

but when trying to use the WordPress HTTP API:

```
    $the_body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( wp_remote_get( TCS_CPDF_REMOTE_ZIP ) );

    file_put_contents( TCS_CPDF_LOCAL_ZIP, $the_body );
```

I end up getting a 0KB file, so the above WordPress version is not working.

So how do you download a file from a remote location using the WordPress API?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out [`download_url()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/download_url) - it's only loaded in the admin, so you'll have to include it (or write your own) if needed on the front-end.

From `download_url()` you can use:

```
$response = wp_remote_get( 
    TCS_CPDF_REMOTE_ZIP, 
    array( 
        'timeout'  => 300, 
        'stream'   => true, 
        'filename' => TCS_CPDF_LOCAL_ZIP 
    ) 
);
```

Comment: `download_url()` always returning this error : `WP_Error Object ( [errors:WP_Error:private] => Array ( [http_404] => Array ( [0] => ) ) [error_data:WP_Error:private] => Array ( ) )` what's the problem here?

Comment: `http_404` - i.e. not found.

Comment: but the url is working when I am trying to open it using browser..

Comment: What is the  URL? Just because it works for you is not to say they haven't blocked remote agents like WordPress.

Comment: here is the url `http://theme.fm/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/image-sizes-in-wordpress-150x120.png`. It is just for testing purpose...

Comment: I get a 404 Not Found.

Comment: my bad... sorry.. this one.. http://theme.fm/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Creating-_your_own_dashboard-150x120.jpg

Comment: Works fine for me. If you're still stuck, post a new question & link to this one.

Answer (score 2):

If you're in WordPress Admin, you have the function `download_url()` available ([see codex description](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/download_url)).

`download_url()` downloads the file, makes it available in a temp file, and returns the name of a file which you copy/rename and then unlink.  See `download_url()` source here in [wp-admin/includes/file.php for more details](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8/src/wp-admin/includes/file.php#L467).

The above answer mentioning download_url() appears to have a wp_remote_get() example - an example for download_url() being:

```
$permfile = 'safefilename.jpg';
$tmpfile = download_url( $url, $timeout = 300 );
copy( $tmpfile, $permfile );
unlink( $tmpfile ); // must unlink afterwards
```

Obviously this is very nice.  Of course, you'd want to ensure $permfile is sanitized nicely if it is based on an externally supplied filename.

Answer (score 2):

```
$your_pdf_path = 'https://example.com/Fortrydelsesformular.pdf';

if (!class_exists('WP_Http'))
    include_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-http.php' );
$http = new WP_Http();
$response = $http->request($your_pdf_path);
if ($response['response']['code'] != 200) {
    return false;
}
$upload = wp_upload_bits(basename($your_pdf_path), null, $response['body']);
if (!empty($upload['error'])) {
    return false;
}
$file_path = $upload['file'];
```

If you print out the `$upload` , you will get below

```
Array
(
    [file] => /var/www/aug15/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Fortrydelsesformular.pdf
    [url] => https://myadomain.com/Fortrydelsesformular.pdf
    [type] => application/pdf
    [error] => 
)
```